# Null float values in Stupid table jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery

I have null values for float data and sorting it using stupidtable.js plugin. The Sorting order produced is incorrect because of null data.

How can I handle such specific situations?

Comment: Filter out null data first?

Comment: what code do you have now ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to massage the data first.  If null data should be shown as zero, replace null values with zeroes.

Comment: How will you replace null values with zeroes.. ? Is this correct data-sort-value="0.0"?

Comment: Stupid Table Plugin author here. @BjornTipling's advice is correct. We intentionally decided to not try and provide default values for invalid data. You can view the discussion and reasoning here: https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin/issues/106

Answer (score 0):

try catch? lets see some code maybe?

You could search the table for null variables with a nested for loop like so

try{

for(A)
  for(B){

if(table[A][B] != null){

system.out.println("the variable at table[A][B] was null");
}

}

}catch{

//deal with the null variables
}

Answer (score 0):

I took a peek at the comparison functions in [stupidTable.js](https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin/blob/master/stupidtable.js). For `float` data types, it performs a simple subtraction expression, and `parseFloat`'s the arguments:

```
    "float": function(a, b) { 
      return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b); 
    }
```

A parseFloat on an empty string returns `NaN`, which evaluates the entire expression to `NaN`...

If you don't want to replace `null` values with zeroes, you should probably fork this plugin and modify this particular function.

Comment: "float": function(a, b) {
  return (parseFloat(a)||0) - (parseFloat(b)||0);
} Would this work?